# Cannot send http post request to springboot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http

When I send an HTTP post request to spring boot rest API from my angular application, request is failing with below error

> Browser Error

```
    HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type
    Type Status Report

    Description: The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format 
    not supported by this method on the target resource
```

> Spring boot console error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        .......
```

**What I have tried so far**

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457818/5477211) solution mentioned, i have added the necessary headers to the request from angular end

```
this.http.post(ipUrl, args, { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'})});
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842512/5477211) answer, I have added `getters/setters` to the Model objects

I want to know where i went wrong and how to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Springboot Rest Controller method

```
@PostMapping("/login")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseWrapper<WebUser> login(@RequestBody LoginData loginData){
    try {
      return loginService.loginProcess(loginData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
      ProgrammerAlert.printStackTrace(ex);
      return new ResponseWrapper<>(ResponseWrapper.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please update the question with code for REST controller? Have you set produces and consumes in the controller method?

Comment: @Smile I didn't add `produces /consumes` to the controller method as I'm using `@PostMapping()` not `@RequestMapping()`. Please see the updated question

Comment: Does it work if you try from some other tool like Postman or Soap UI?

Comment: @Smile No. Same error for postman as well

Comment: What is the ”args” parameter?

Comment: It's having data to be sent to server

Answer (score 0):

Could you write your controller in this way. and see if it responds.

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public  ResponseWrapper<WebUser> login(...){
     .
     .
     .
  }
```

Is there a reason that you do not want to use RequestMapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reasons not to add `produces` and `consumes` properties?

```java
@PostMapping("/login", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
public @ResponseBody ResponseWrapper<WebUser> login(@RequestBody LoginData loginData){
  try {
    return loginService.loginProcess(loginData);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
    ProgrammerAlert.printStackTrace(ex);
    return new ResponseWrapper<>(ResponseWrapper.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

or,

Did you add any JSON message converter, like jackson? Check your application has below dependency

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have changed my controller as you mentioned. Now spring boot console not showing any errors. But browser giving `HTTP 406` error code. any idea of why it's giving the error?

Comment: @Junyoung answer is correct, please refer my updated answer to correct the Accept header alone, produces should be "application/json" - same as accept header

Answer (score 0):

your return object should be converted to JSON properly. Add Jackson to you pom (separately from starter web) and retry.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: First, I got exception in spring boot console and `http-415` error in browser. After add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` to controller annotation  both issues were fixed. But now i'm getting `http-406` error

Comment: It is because your response from the server is still Not Acceptable from browser. Make sure you are receiving a Json response by Network tab in developer tools or by using postman like tool.

Comment: In the browser network tab or postman, I'm getting empty response.

Comment: I don't think my request is getting processed by server. I have added some `System.out.println()`. It's not printing anything

Comment: debug line by line. use debug tools in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As per your recent edit, you're now getting *406 Not Acceptable*, to fix this error, keep the media type of your Spring boot application's response same as the **Accept** header of your client. Try the following.

1. Change the value of produces to **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** as you have  accept header in client as "application/json". Also please note:

> APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 is deprecated in favor of APPLICATION_JSON

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html

2. For those who are facing a similar issue, you can also check if there is any typo in Accept header as I often face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same issue, I guess the answer of this question is very clear

```
HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type
```

while sending the request make the content type json instead of text